# SQL Query for finding values that do not exist in one table, with WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to compile a query for the following and wonder if anyone can please help (I'm a SQL newbie).

I have two tables:

(1) `student_details`, which contains the columns: `student_id (PK), firstname, surname` (and others, but not relevant to this query)

(2) `membership_fee_payments`, which contains details of monthly membership payments for each student and contains the columns: `membership_fee_payments_id (PK), student_id (FK), payment_month, payment_year, amount_paid`

I need to create the following query:

- *which students **have not** paid fees for March 2012?*

The query could be for any month/year, March is just an example. I want to return in the query `firstname, surname` from `student_details`.

I can query successfully who has paid for a certain month and year, but I can't work out how to query who has not paid!

Here is my query for finding out who has paid:

```
SELECT student_details.firstname, student_details.surname, 
FROM student_details
INNER JOIN membership_fee_payments 
  ON student_details.student_id = membership_fee_payments.student_id
WHERE membership_fee_payments.payment_month = "March" 
 AND membership_fee_payments.payment_year = "2012" 
ORDER BY student_details.firstname
```

I have tried a left join and left outer join but get the same result. I think perhaps I need to use NOT EXISTS or IS NULL but I haven't had much luck writing the right query yet.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm partial to using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` Typically that would look something like this

```
SELECT D.firstname, D.surname
FROM student_details D 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM membership_fee_payments P  
                  WHERE P.student_id = D.student_id 
                      AND P.payment_year = '2012' 
                      AND P.payment_month = 'March'
                 )
```

This is know an a correlated subquery as it contains references to the outer query. This allows you to include your join criteria in the subquery without necessarily writing a JOIN. Also, most RDBMS query optimizers will implement this as a SEMI JOIN which does not typically do as much 'work' as a complete join.

Comment: +1 I'd prefer this to my own solution, this one is easier to read :D

Comment: @jnhamilton: You might want to ["accept"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this solution by clicking the V mark beside the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `left join`. When the payment is missing, all the columns in the `left join` table will be `null`:

```
SELECT student_details.firstname, student_details.surname, 
FROM student_details
LEFT JOIN membership_fee_payments 
  ON student_details.student_id = membership_fee_payments.student_id
     AND membership_fee_payments.payment_month = "March" 
     AND membership_fee_payments.payment_year = "2012" 
WHERE membership_fee_payments.student_id is null
ORDER BY student_details.firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write following query. This will gives your expected output.

SELECT student_details.firstname, 
       student_details.surname, 
FROM student_details
Where 
student_details.student_id Not in 
(SELECT membership_fee_payments.student_id 
from membership_fee_payments
WHERE 
membership_fee_payments.payment_year = '2012' 
AND membership_fee_payments.payment_month = 'March'
)